# Final Step in calculating option prices under the Heston Stochastic Volatility Model

Tags: complex-analysis, stochastic-calculus, finance

Let:
$$
\alpha = -\frac{u^2}{2}-\frac{iu}{2}+jiu\\
\beta = \lambda-\rho \eta i u - j \rho \eta\\
\gamma = \frac{\eta ^2}{2}\\
$$

where $j \in \{0,1\}$ and $i^2=-1$, $g=\frac{r_-}{r_+}$ and $r_{\pm}=\frac{\beta\pm \sqrt{\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma}}{2\gamma}=\frac{\beta \pm d }{\eta^2}$.
Then let:
$$
D(u,\tau)=r_-\frac{1-e^{-d\tau}}{1-ge^{-d\tau}}\\
C(u,\tau)=\lambda \left[\tau r_--\frac{2}{\eta^2}log(\frac{1-ge^{-d\tau}}{1-g}) \right]
$$
Where $\lambda$ is a constant.

For the function:
$$
\hat{P}_j(u,v,\tau)=\frac{1}{iu}\exp\left[C(u,\tau)\bar{v}+D(u,\tau)v \right]
$$
$\bar{v}\in \mathscr R$.

Show that:

$$ P_j(x,v,\tau)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iux}}{2\pi} \hat{P_j}(u,v,\tau)du\\ = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty Re\left[\frac{\exp[C_j(u,\tau)\bar{v}+D_j(u,\tau)v+iux]}{iu} \right]du $$

This result comes up in a text I am reading on stochastic volatility models, it is stated but not proven, the math involved is probably way above my level, but it would be great to see the steps involved in proving this. I guess it just amounts to showing the imaginary part of this integral is equal to half.

I don't mean for the question to be lazy, I have worked through all other parts of this relatively long proof, this technique seems to be used a lot in stochastic volatility/liquidity models which I am interested in studying further, and that's the reason I posted.

Comment: Once the many typos are cleared up, this seems to be a simple application of the formula for the inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: @Did I cleared up any typos - i think, please point them out if you see any.

Comment: @Did how is it simple? Doesn't the dependence on $\beta$ and subsequently i of both C and D make it pretty difficult? or at least convoluted..

Comment: Precisely! All these details are irrelevant, at the end and fixing all the other parameters $v$, $j$, $\rho$, $\eta$, etc., one knows a function $\hat G:u\mapsto\hat G(u)$ and one asks for the function $G:x\mapsto G(x)$.

Comment: @Did if its not too much trouble, could you show a few steps of the result?

Comment: What's $C_j$ and $D_j$? Moreover, there is a bracket missing in the last formula.

Comment: sorry, fixed now

Comment: You still have not explained what $C_j$ is, nor what $D_j$ is. Moreover, the function $\hat{P}_j$ has no explicit dependence on $j$.

Comment: but there is a dependence of C and D on r which depends on $\alpha , \beta$, they in turn depend on j?

Comment: @SDiv, your assumption about $\bar{v}$ is correct, my mistake about missing the equals sign on the 4th line

Comment: nvm, the fourth line should not have been there, i had written down the definition of D twice.

Comment: it is the mean, which is a constant in the problem

Comment: what textbook are you looking at? what pg?

Comment: The Volatility Surface by James Gatheral - the proof is explained in chapter 2

Comment: well, not explained, he skips over this step obviously, and many others

Comment: what are your thoughts on my answer? is there something else you want clarified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gatheral leaves out something important and it makes all the difference for the derivation but not the final result. Specifically, on pg. 17 he states the following, $$\hat{P}(u,v,0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Theta(x)e^{-iux}dx=\frac{1}{iu},$$ where $\Theta(x)$ is the Heaviside unit step function (as defined in his Eq. 2.7, take a look at his definition and convince yourself that it is basically the same as Wikipedias). But this is not true - there is a Dirac delta missing. See rule 313 column 3 on WP - [Tables of important Fourier transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions). The equation should be: $$\hat{P}(u,v,0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Theta(x)e^{-iux}dx=\frac{1}{iu}+\pi\delta(u),$$ where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta distribution. Next, we have $$\hat{P}_j(u,v,t)=\exp(C[u,\tau]\bar{v}+D[u,\tau]v)\hat{P}_j(u,v,0)\\
=(\frac{1}{iu}+\pi\delta[u])\exp(C[u,\tau]\bar{v}+D[u,\tau]v).$$ Then $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{iux}}{2\pi}\hat{P}_j(u)\text{d}u = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{iux}}{2\pi}(\frac{1}{iu}+\pi\delta[u])\exp(C[u,\tau]\bar{v}+D[u,\tau]v)\text{d}u.$$ Lets split this into two parts. Lets consider the integral over the delta function first. Noting that $C(0,\tau)=0$ and $D(0,\tau)=0$ we have $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{iux}}{2\pi}(\pi\delta[u])\exp(C[u,\tau]\bar{v}+D[u,\tau]v)\text{d}u=\frac{1}{2}.$$ Now consider the part with $\frac{1}{iu}$. Let $$\hat{P}'_j:=\frac{1}{iu}\exp(C[u,\tau]\bar{v}+D[u,\tau]v)$$

The important thing to notice is, assuming $j,\rho,\eta,\lambda$ and $\tau$ are real, that $r_\pm(u)$ is conjugate-even in $u$. That is, $r_\pm(-u)=r_\pm^\ast(u)$, where $\ast$ denotes complex conjugate. Then g and d and therefore $D$ and $C$ and therefore $\hat{P}'_j$ are conjugate-even. I make the additional assumption that $\bar{v}$ indicates the mean of the real parameter $v$ and not the complex conjugate. Then, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{iux}}{2\pi}\hat{P}'_j(u)\text{d}u = \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^{iux}}{2\pi}\hat{P}'_j(u)\text{d}u + \int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{iux}}{2\pi}\hat{P}'_j(u)\text{d}u \\ = \int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-iux}}{2\pi}\hat{P}'_j(-u)\text{d}u + \int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{iux}}{2\pi}\hat{P}'_j(u)\text{d}u \\ = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^\infty \left [ e^{-iux}\hat{P'}_j^\ast(u) +  e^{iux}\hat{P}'_j(u) \right ]\text{d}u \\ = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty  \text{Re}\left[e^{iux}\hat{P}'_j(u) \right ]\text{d}u. $$ On the last line I have used the identity $2\text{Re}(z)=z+z^\ast$.

Putting it all together gives $$P_j(x,v,\tau)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty  \text{Re}\left[e^{iux}\hat{P}'_j(u) \right ]\text{d}u,$$ which is the solution in the book.

**Update:**
If you remain unsatisfied and are skeptical that Gatheral omitted the delta, consider this:
On pg 19 Gatheral gives the conditions $C(u,0)=0$ and $D(u,0)=0$. Note again that according to his definition, $\hat{P}(u,v,0)=1/(iu)$. Then, using the inverse transform as he defines in Eq. 2.8, this gives $$\Theta(x)=\lim_{\tau \rightarrow 0}P_j(x,v,\tau)=\lim_{\tau \rightarrow 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{2\pi iu}\exp(C[u,\tau]\bar{v}+D[u,\tau]v)e^{iux}du\\=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{2\pi iu}e^{iux}du \\ = \frac{1}{2}\text{sgn}(x) \neq \Theta(x)$$ where on the last line we used the inverse transform version of rule 309 on the WP fourier transform page. Notice that this answer is off by exactly $1/2$! That is, $1/2+ (1/2)\text{sgn}(x)=\Theta(x)$. In other words, Gatheral omitted the delta and his derivation as printed is not self-consistent. It should be noted, however, that the omission does not affect his final result (which remains valid).

Comment: For those interested, the Google books preview is at http://books.google.ch/books?id=9Y8rWE6mLOEC&printsec=frontcover on pgs. 16-21.

Comment: The original paper is at doi: 10.1093/rfs/6.2.327